# Replacing symbol from object file at compile time. For example swapping out main

Tags: c++, g++

Here's the use case:

I have a `.cpp` file which has functions implemented in it.  For sake of example say it has the following:

`[main.cpp]`

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int);

int foo(int a) {
    return a * a;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        std::cout << foo(i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to perform some amount of automated testing on the function `foo` in this file but would need to replace out the `main()` function to do my testing.  Preferably I'd like to have a separate file like this that I could link in over top of that one:

`[mymain.cpp]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

extern int foo(int);

int main() {
    assert(foo(1) == 1);
    assert(foo(2) == 4);
    assert(foo(0) == 0);
    assert(foo(-2) == 4);        

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like (if at all possible) to avoid changing the original `.cpp` file in order to do this -- though this would be my approach if this is not possible:

1. do a replace for `"(\s)main\s*\("` ==> `"\1__oldmain\("`
2. compile as usual.

The environment I am targeting is a linux environment with g++.

Comment: I might recommend searching for / learning about automated unit testing in C++?  It's a fair question but sounds like you'er about to major reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for formatting your question properly. I honestly appreciate it.

Comment: Why not leave the asserts and use the NDEBUG macro to remove them at compile time?

Comment: Surely any solution you come up with is going to be more difficult to implement and maintain and justify that just putting `foo` in a separate TU like you should have in the first place? And writing a separate `main` to exercise it?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Interesting idea. It'll work for this specific example but I think any more than four (i.e. heading into full test set territory) and you're swiftly backing yourself into a corner of code that does two things when it should do one. There's a reason we generally write unit tests separately.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why - what is wrong with having debugging asserts in your code - the a pre/post conditions that must be true which are not needed in production code. Nothing wrong with putting them in, that is why assert was created

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Pre- and post-conditions are absolutely appropriate, as you say. However, that's not what the OP is talking about, unless you count "this function always gives the right output for any input" as a pre-/post-condition. I don't.

Comment: Might it help if the OP states explicitly that, as I imagine, the real `foo` is far more complex than a single multiplication operation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True - in this case you are correct and cppunit or some such would be more appropriate.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Right -- the way I interpret this question is that the OP is trying to hack a unit testing scenario around an existing implementation, where function definitions are not extricated into logically-separated TUs.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: perhaps I should have maybe clarified my use case a little more clearly, I'm not attempting to write a testing framework.  I'm attempting to improve an autograding tool (which grades student code).  Our currently hacked together implementation does the regex nastiness I described above.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I can't notify two people in one comment so this is a dummy comment... ^

Comment: @AnthonySottile (yeah 2 people notifications would be nice) If you cannot/not allowed to modify the original code - then hrow away the regex and write some unit tests that test for all your conditions. That include the needed code - seriously check out cppunit framework.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I briefly looked through the cppunit documentation and could not find anything that led me to believe I could use it to test a function defined in a file that also has a main defined.  The testing part isn't the difficult part, the difficult part is eliminating the `main` symbol from the students code.

Comment: @AnthonySottile Simple do not include it in linking your test app - you create two binaries. One that tests the code - and one that is production quality - a test suite is supposed to be standalone.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: The student submits a file like `main.cpp` above. How do I not link the `main` symbol from `main.cpp` into my output.  This is my question.

Comment: @AnthonySottile Ok - it is obvious I do not understand your reason for doing this - are you looking for an automated way to test student submitted code. Are they requirements that main should only contain X

Comment: @AdrianCornish: The class already has a methodology for automated testing -- this question is not looking to find that.  The students have several projects.  In each the students are required to implement specific functions, and a main function which brings these together to run code.  Our testing suite looks to test both their main() implementation (by compiling their code as-is) as well as testing their individual function implementations.  I'm attempting to improve on the terrible hack we do right (regex out `int main`, and cat a new one on the bottom of the file).

Comment: @AnthonySottile This may be incredibly simplistic - but why include the student's main.cc version and include your own instead for this test. I agree the regex is totally horrible. ie `g++ -o teststudent teacher/main.cpp` vs `g++ -o student student/main.cpp`

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I want our main, with their function implementations.

Comment: My simple idea should work if their function implementations are in different source files. If they are all in main.cc then no. Would it be hard to ask the students to do that - a multi file solution?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: We do that for later projects, but just starting out multiple files is incredibly intimidating -- header files make their heads spin.

Comment: Indeed it is at first - the the best thing I can think of is to make sure your main is last on the compile/link line and use `-Wl,-zmuldefs` on the link line

Comment: That last idea is a good one.....

Comment: @AdrianCornish: So I read the man page for g++ last night / this morning and I found a not as terrible solution.  I'll type it up and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate answering my own question, but here's a solution I ended up finding deep in the man page of `g++`, I've tested it and it works to what I would want it to...

`g++` has the `-D` flag which allows you to define macros when compiling object files.  I know you are thinking "ugh macros" but hear me out...  You can use the macro definition to effectively rename a symbol.  In my case, I can run the following command to generate an object file of my students code without their main file: `g++ -D main=__students_main__ main.cpp -c -o main.nomain.o`.

This creates an object file with their `int main` defined as `int __students_main__`.  Now this isn't necessarily callable directly as they could have defined main as `int main(void)` or with the various combinations of `argc` and `argv`, but it allows me to effectively compile out their function.

The final compile looks like this:

```
g++ -c -D main=__students_main__ main.cpp -o main.nomain.o
g++ -c mymain.cpp -o mymain.o
g++ main.nomain.o mymain.o -o mymainstudentsfoo.out
```

For my purposes, I wanted to create a Makefile that would accomplish this automagically (ish) and I feel that is relevant to this discussion so I'll post what I came up with:

```
HDIR=./ # Not relevant to question, but we have headers in a separate directory
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I $(HDIR)
NOMAIN=-D main=__student_main__ # The main renaming magic

.SECONDARY: # I forget exactly what this does, I seem to remember it is a hack to prevent deletion of .o files

cpp = $(wildcard *.cpp)
obj = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(cpp))
objnomain = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.nomain.o,$(cpp))

all: $(obj) $(objnomain)

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.out

%.nomain.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(NOMAIN) -c $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^
```

Comment: Slight risk with the preprocessor approach in that it replaces any matching token, not limited to the function name.  An alternative on UNIX to use *objcopy* to rename the symbol: `objcopy --redefine-sym main=__students_main__ $@` (or a computed replacement based on the filename?).

Comment: Great ! The -D renaming trick also works with gcc. It allows me to wrap fuzzer code with a main() function around application code with a main function and to call the original main for fuzzing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--allow-multiple-definition` option of `ld`*:

`[a.c]`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() { return 3; }
int bar() { return 4; }

int main(void)
{
    printf("foo: %i\n", foo());
    return 0;
}
```

`[b.c]`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bar();

int main(void)
{
    printf("bar: %i\n", bar());
    return 0;
}
```

`[shell]`

```
$ gcc -Wall -c a.c
$ gcc -Wall -c b.c

$ gcc -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition a.o b.o -o foobar && foobar
foo: 3
$ gcc -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition b.o a.o -o foobar && foobar
bar: 4
```

*: At your own risk :)

Comment: +1 this accomplishes what I want, however my students often have code that doesn't compile including errors due to duplicately defined symbols (this is an intro course) and I would like to still surface those errors.  Also the compilation is likely going to occur through a makefile and I wouldn't necessarily like the non deterministic ordering of files to lead to consequences in compiled output.

Comment: es, those were the risks I was thinking of. Perhaps you could mitigate the problem by linking everything else first, but this is still too much hackery for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

I support 'djechlin's suggestion.
But if you want something quick and dirty, here's a suggestion:

You can define a macro and wrap your function calls like this,

```
#ifdef MYTESTING
#define ASSERTEQUAL(fn, parm, ret) \
assert( fn ( parm ) == ret )
#else
#define ASSERTEQUAL(fn, parm, ret) fn ( parm )
#endif
```

And in your main function use the following call,
    ASSERTEQUAL( foo, i, 4);

Use the following compilation flag to enable the customized macro behavior.

```
-DMYTESTING
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading correctly, how does this prevent `"duplicate symbol _main"` ?

Comment: My bad, i think i understood this in a different sense. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this at compile time. You need a link time solution. (Or to make use of the preprocessor.)

In either case, you'd probably want to separate the "regular" and "testing" symbols and selectively include their source files in compilation, or object files in linking.*

Though I'd rather use a unit testing framework or at least `NDEBUG` for `assert()`s.

*e.g.:

```
#ifdef TESTING
#include "main-testing.c"
#else
#include "main.c"
#endif
```

or

```
ifdef TESTING
OBJS += main-testing.o
else
OBJS += main.o
endif
```

Update: I just realized that you're specifically looking for a solution where main-testing.o's main would override main.o's (right?). I'll keep this answer and add another one for the "override" solution.